A 12th-grade physics question about inductors
I'm a 12th-grade student learning about inductors, and there's a question that’s been bothering me. I’m not an expert, which is why I’m asking here. If anyone knows the answer, please explain it as if you're explaining it to a 12th grader.
I'm studying inductors, and according to my school textbook, a change in current ($dI/dt$) through an inductor produces a back emf. I know this can be explained using electromagnetism, so I tried to understand it in more depth, particularly the concept of length contraction (Lorentz contraction) and how it relates to creating a magnetic field.
Here's my thought process:
Suppose we have a DC circuit with a rheostat (or some device) that allows us to adjust the voltage. I set the voltage to 5 V, which results in a constant current (meaning no back emf is produced because $dI/dt = 0'). Now, if I change the voltage from 5 V to 10 V, three things happen:

At 5 V, the current is constant, so there’s no back emf.

2.At 10 V, the current is constant again, so still no back emf.
3.During the transition from 5 V to 10 V (I’ll call this the “transition time” or "TT"), there is a changing current, which should produce a back emf.
Teachers often say that this transition happens almost instantaneously, But it’s precisely during this TT that the back emf is created, which is why I think it’s important to understand what’s happening here.
My reasoning is as follows: If back emf is explained using magnetism, then during the transition time, electrons in the inductor windings should feel a repulsive force from adjacent windings. This repulsion must have a consistent direction. Otherwise, if it were random, the forces would cancel each other out, and we wouldn’t get a net back emf.
Also, closer windings should mean stronger inductance, at infinite pitch the inductor is a straight wire, which seems to support this idea.
The big question:
How can I connect all these concepts? I have some ideas, but I'm not fully convinced. My primary question is how a inductor works? My secondary question is more fundamental: What actually happens when I increase the voltage from 5 V to 10 V? Does the electric field change instantly throughout the conductor, moving at the speed of light? at this time what happens? And, what is magnetic potential energy in a real sense?
Can someone explain this in a way that a 12th grader would understand?

Have you asked your 12th grade teacher for help?

He is at the same situation as i am . he can explain how it works .but what really happening in that deep level nah he can't

Thinking about Lorentz contraction as the source of magnetism can quickly become confusing. Here is Veritasium's attempt to explain it. How Special Relativity Makes Magnets Work. Here is dXoverdteqprogress' follow up. Veritasium's 'How Special Relativity Makes Magnets Work' - EXPLAINED (better)

The electricity model which is commonly learned in schools is best described as a "lump model": We ignore all the details (contained in Maxwell's equation) and describe the result using electrical components. Hence, don't expect that the following description is scientifically correct -- it is adapted to school level.
1. How does an inductor work?
As you stated in your question, the key effect of an inductor is that it opposes a change in the current. The simple description is that a change in the electric current generates a magnetic field -- which is consistent with Maxwell's equations. Here are simpler steps:

Biot-Savart's law: A constant electric current generates a magnetic field. Hence, at 5V a magnetic fields surrounds the wire.
Lenz's law: A change of a magnetic field flux generates a magnetic field, which opposes the change. Hence, Lenz's law also applies if the starting point is 0V: The inductor opposes the change.

2. Does the electric field change instantly throughout the conductor, moving at the speed of light?
In physics nothing happens instantly. Although it is true that in our "lump model" we usually do not include the finite velocity of the speed of light -- because the time difference is so small that we don't care -- it is important to understand that the speed of light is considered to be an absolute limit to transfer information -- and a change of a field contains information.
The information (change of the current/voltage) is not transferred along the wire, but it is transferred by an electric magnetic wave, which spreads radially outwards starting at the voltage generator. Thus, if we place a voltage generator and a light bulb $1m$ next to each another, but we connect the two using a wire which has a length $\ell = c_0\cdot 1s$ on either side, the light bulb would turn on almost immediately after switching on the voltage -- it does not take 1s! What happens is that the EM wave radiates outwards and changes the density of the surface charges of the wire. The surface charges are responsible for the voltage difference, because inside the conductor the electric field vanishes.
In school we often learn that electrons are supplied by the current generator. The common picture is analog to a "garden hose" where on the start water flows in and at the end the same water flows out. This picture does not really describe what is happening, because the electrons experience only an insignificant net velocity towards the positive voltage.

Regarding the magnetism from Lorentz contraction: so that is when you have a wire with a current $\lambda\vec v$ making a mag field $\vec B$ which bends the path of a fiducial charge moving $\vec v$, and in the frame of the "moving" charge, there is only an electric field $\vec E'$ sourced from the differential Lorentz contraction of the wire's ions $q_+'$ and the current's (formerly) moving electrons $q_-'$?
If so, then that is a very cool explanation of hoe $j_{\mu} = (q, \vec j)$ transforms, leading to self consistent application of the Lorentz force law ($\vec f = q(\vec E + \vec v \times \vec B)$).
I have some banger answers, and even plots, somewhere on this site, all about that.
It's no uncommon to see ppl ask follow-up questions such as "what about spin?" or "What if the charge is moving perpendicular to the wire"?
Well, of course relativity still works, but this sort of explanation is not helpful. The $\vec B$ from $L/\gamma$ as described works because the problem is set up so both the at rest frame and moving frame have static charge and current distribution (for the sources), and the only thing that is changing: the fiducial charge in the rest frame is changing trivially, that is: it does not modify the description of the problem.
Now the point of that long story was to convince you that an inductor is not a suitable charge/current distribution to be amenable to such analysis. If you want to pursue that line, then you need to fully understand Bell's Spaceship Paradox and see why it's basically the same problem. (Also see my posts about them on this site: I actually "do the LT", which is sometimes the only way to close out an SR doubt).
Regarding changes in fields and the TT and all that...that's another area where I sound like a broken record on this site. I recommend reading and understanding Jefimenko's equations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations).
They are a formulation of EM that respects causality. In it, any and all fields ${\bf E}({\bf r}, t)$  and ${\bf B}({\bf r}, t)$ are only cause by charges $\rho$, currents ${\bf j}$, and their time derivatives $\dot\rho$, $\dot{{\bf j}}$ evaluated on the past light cone of $({\bf r}, t)$, that is at position ${\bf r}'$ and times $t'$ that satisfy:
$$ |{\bf r} - {\bf r}'| = c|t-t'| $$
$$ t' < t $$
There is no place for "a changing magnetic field creates an electric field"; rather "sources on the past light-cone generate and electric field with a time derivative that is equal (proportional) to curl of the magnetic field".
So you need to start with a charge and current distribution that leads to a static 5V circuit with constant current flow, and consider how that changes to get to 10V, and go from there.
Also, you want to make the physical model of your circuit as simple as possible, so I am thinking of an inductor with $N=1$ turns. Just a loop, say in the $x-y$ plane (or $\rho, \phi$ plane) with current flowing up along the $z$-axis (or parallel to it, with loop centered on $z=0$).

I am currently a senior in high school. thats what 12th grader phrase actually meant.i don't know university level physics . I got some understanding about what you told and  some don't .thanks for your reply

I feel like you know "answer at the level of a 12th grader" means an answer that uses introductory physics concepts (maybe including basic calculus) and not whatever you were trying to do with Gen Z slang.

@gerome You're welcome. The level of the question shows understanding beyond 12th grade. I don't remember that far back, but we did not have the internet, and physics books were 50-100 dollars each.  I should have included https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TKSfAkWWN0 in the answer. The wiki link to Jefimenko's eq has good discussion of fields and their sources propagating in time, which will address your no. 2 question. I know I didn't answer anything, my goal was to  provided food for thought. Doing this always risks down-votes, but as far as I'm concerned: they can take two seats.
